# How to substitute a string for a control's name and method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am writing a touchscreen restaurant POS package, using SQL Server and Visual Studio in C#. To select an item, I have populated a form with forty iterations of a user-control selection-button that contains a Button control and a Label control. These user-controls comprise a grid, four columns across and ten tows deep, designated A,B,C,D for the columns and 1 through 10 for the rows. Depending on the values in the corresponding Items datatable, I need to make the matching user-control visible, set its button's backcolor, and set the button's text to the name of the Item.  To set the text on the user-control's button, it carries this code:

```
   public string iButtonItem
    {
        get { return iButton.Text; }
        set { iButton.Text = value; }
    }
```

Back in the form, I load the datatable, in which each item has a location field, such as A1 or C8.  Now I need to set up the buttons.
For a given button, say one at position A3, this line of code works perfectly:

```
this.iButtonA3.iButtonItem = row["ItemName"].ToString().TrimEnd();
```

My problem is that rather than have forty sets of Switch / Case code blocks, one for each button, it would be far more elegant to have a single block with a substitution string: "iButton" + locationString + ".iButtonItem"  This is easy in FoxPro, and also possible, I believe, in Visual Basic.  But how can I accomplish it in C#?  Along the way, I have tried using this.Controls.Find but that does not work because of the iButtonItem method of the user-control that I need to call.

Comment: put your buttons in an array/dictionary

Comment: you cant do it like that, but you could add each control to an array and itterate through them

Comment: Is this windows forms?

Comment: "This is easy in FoxPro" Lots of things are easier in a scripting (untyped) language than they in a type-safe language like C#.  I would get used to that if you continue working in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Controls.Find`, to access `iButtonItem` you simply need to cast to your control type that contains it:

```
var uc = this.Controls.Find("iButtonA3", true).FirstOrDefault() as YouUserControlType;
if (uc != null)
    uc.iButtonItem = "Hello";
```

Or alternatively

```
IDictionary<string, YouUserControlType> buttons;

public SomeForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    buttons = new Dictionary<string, YouUserControlType>()
    {
        { "iButtonA1", iButtonA1 },
        { "iButtonA2", iButtonA2 },
    };
}
```

To allow `buttons[nameString].iButtonItem = ...`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are creating the controls in the designer, but I don't think this is the best approach to this problem. You could create all the controls dynamically, add them to a dictionary, and use the dictionary to address these controls latter.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Dictionary<string, UserControl1> myControls = new Dictionary<string, UserControl1>();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // you could create the controls manually (i.e. not in designer)
        //  add them to a dictionary
        //  and also add them to the form, or whatever container you want
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            var newControl = new UserControl1
            {
                Top = (i%10)*30,
                Left = (i/10)*200,
            };
            myControls.Add("iButton" + ("ABCD"[(i / 10)]) + (i % 10), newControl);
            this.Controls.Add(newControl);
        }

        // now you can reference any of these controls like this:
        var letter = "B";
        var num = "8";
        var buttonItem = myControls["iButton" + letter + num].iButtonItem;
    }
}
```

In this example, I create each user control in a for loop, and set the position absolutely. That may not be the best way to layout the controls, but you can use  a **layout container** (e.g. `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel`) if you wish, and add the dynamically created controls to that container instead of adding to the Form itself.